# Hibernate: Bypass generated ID in some case

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two entity Parent and Child. Parent can have only one child so it contains foreign key of a child.

All ID are generated by a custom implementation of IdentifierGenerator. For some entity, I want to set manually the ID. So I found a way in my custom IdentifierGenerator to get the value of the id field.

The problem is that the generator is never called when the id of the child was previously defined and the child was not yet persisted.

parent-hbm.xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all">
    <class name="com.ParentImpl" table="Parent" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
        <cache usage="read-write" />
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="ID" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
            <generator class="com.EntityIdGenerator">
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="child" class="com.ChildImpl" foreign-key="CHILDSC" cascade="all" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="CHILD_FK" not-null="true" sql-type="BIGINT" unique="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

child-hbm.xml file:

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
    <column name="ID" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
    <generator class="com.EntityIdGenerator">
    </generator>
</id>
```

How can I change this behaviour ?

Any idea ?

THanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code. Your custom generator should appear in the @GenericGenerator annotation on your identifier

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047175/save-new-object-with-hibernate-using-supplied-id?

Comment: No it's not duplicate because in my case for the same enity I want to set ID manually or/and automtically (generated with the idGenerator)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Generator, have you tried configuring it for manual ids and then using an Interceptor or Event Listener that generates a value for the cases when it's not manually assigned?

Sarah

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use Interceptor because the onSave() method is never called for an entity with "assigned" generator and no id setted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @PrePersist annotation to generate an ID if it doesn't already have one.  I was surprised by your comment that it couldn't be done with interceptors or event listeners, so I decided to try it out.

Here's an example of how to do it.  I have a class "Test" that has a manually assigned id and then I implemented a @PrePersist method to assign the ID to the hashCode() value if it doesn't already have an ID.  You can substitute whatever generation scheme you want in place of the hashCode() call.

```
@Entity 
@Table (name="Test")
public class Test{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")    
    private String id;

    @Column(name="PROPERTY")
    private String property;

    public Test() {
    }

    ... // Other constructors, getters and setters

    @PrePersist
    void generateId() {
        if (id == null) {
            id = Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
        }
    }
```

I tested out both assigned and unassigned ids with both creating new entities and updating existing entities and didn't run into any issues.

Example of creating new entity:

```
Test assigned = new Test("assigned", "p1");
Test generate = new Test();
generate.setProperty("p2");         
manager.persist(assigned);
manager.persist(generate);
manager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Example of updating existing entity:

```
Test update = manager.find(Test.class, "assigned");
actionUpdate.setProperty("imageUpdated");

Test update2 = manager.find(Test.class, "some-generated-id");
update2.setProperty("videoUpdated");

manager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Sarah