# Using multiple id generators in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have introduced a custom id generator in hbm.xml. But, at times for some use cases I need to persist explicit ids in my table where I don't want the custom Id generator triggered. Is there any way of doing this? Or is there any option to have multiple custom id generators and switch between them at run-time?

Comment: Have you tried the easy way?...set id manually before persist?

Comment: I think eventhough I manually set it, at the end Hibernate will call the custom id generator and it will overwrite the manually given id.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at javadoc of [`IdentifierGenerator.generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/id/IdentifierGenerator.html):

> **Parameters**:
>  session -
>  **object** - the entity or toplevel
>   collection for which the id is being generated
>  **Returns**:
>  a
>   new identifier

Maybe a solution can be check for `@Id` annotated field and looks if field was manually valued or let your domain object implements a custom interface and write an extractor class to extract information from persisting object in some way (reflection, manual written code or other solution)

Answer (score 1):

If you can implement the logic yourself for when you want to use the generator and when you want to skip it, you should be able to do this using the @PrePersist annotation.  See the following post:

[Hibernate: Bypass generated ID in some case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630602/hibernate-bypass-generated-id-in-some-case/18669620#18669620)

Hope this helps.

Sarah